# Webview cookie Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, webview, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have tried to access an HTTPS page in a webview control where I need to pass cookie to be able to access the site. I haven't been able to find any example of it working in the new Windows 8 webview. Can somebody help me figure out how to pass a session cookie to the webview before the page is loaded?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code that shows what you have tried so far?

Comment: It's nothing to post, because of simply can't implement what i found in the other posts, because no such property exists, like Document, etc so can't pass the cookie. I found some way how should i do (create empty page and pass the cookie, or invoke some DLL etc) I searched in the stackoverflow or msnd forums.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you asked the same question on MSDN. So posting the link here for those who is looking for the answer.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/winappswithcsharp/thread/05e46a0a-e913-469d-a4a5-4a805dcf158a

On the other hand, if the project is based on javascript/html, then my own experience is: No, there is no way to do that at this point. I was on a similar javascript metro project and had to use iframe to make the request and postMessage to work things around.